# How to enable multi-select dropdown on radio button select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a multi select dropdown and two radio buttons. By default `No` should be checked and the drop down should be disabled. On change to `Yes` it should be enabled but it's not working. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.

This is my html:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label>Action Taken:</label>
                        <input type="radio" class="check" name="check" value="Yes">Yes
                        <input type="radio" class="check" name="check" value="No" checked>No
                        <select name="action[]" id="action" multiple class="action form-control" disabled>
                        <option value="Offcycle Salary Revision">Offcycle Salary Revision</option>
</select>
```

This is my javascript:

```
<script>
$('.check').change(function(){

   let select = $(this).parents('.form-group:first').find('select') ; 

   if( $(this).val() == 'Yes')
        select.attr('disabled' , false );
   else 
        select.attr('disabled' , true );

});
</script>
```

This is my javascript for multiselect:

```
$('#action').multiselect({
  nonSelectedText: 'Select Action',
  buttonWidth:'465px',
  maxHeight:450,
  includeSelectAllOption: true
 });
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? It's working fine for a single select dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target element which are dynamically created by *mutliselect*  . So , you can target button which have `mutliselect` class then change attribute of that button.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#action').multiselect({
    nonSelectedText: 'Select Action',
    buttonWidth: '465px',
    maxHeight: 450,
    includeSelectAllOption: true
  });


  $('.check').change(function() {
    //targetting mutliselect button
    $(this).closest(".form-group").find(".multiselect").attr('disabled', $(this).val() == 'Yes' ? false : true);
  });
  $('.check').trigger("change") //for triggering on page load..
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Action Taken:</label>
  <input type="radio" class="check" name="check" value="Yes">Yes
  <input type="radio" class="check" name="check" value="No" checked>No
  <select name="action[]" id="action" multiple class="action form-control">
    <option value="Offcycle Salary Revision">Offcycle Salary Revision</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: This Works fine but I have more multi select in form all those are getting disabled...I want only this dropdown to be disabled